# problem with retrieving object from Tcl_HashTable for destroy object

Tags: c, api, tcl

I am trying to use Tcl C api for creating a hashtable of my C elements and link them to some string (key is string and the value is pointer to my C object).
my problem is that when I want to create the destroy function for my object, this destroy function gets clientData that is pointer that can be casted to my object type but I can't find this object in the hash table with this pointer (because the key's are strings).
How can I solve this issue? is Tcl_linkvar is something that will be usefull in this case?

I will provide some code that I wrote:

```
Tcl_InitHashTable(hash_table,TCL_STRING_KEYS);
...
int addMyObj(My_Obj * _obj , const char* _obj_name) {

    Tcl_HashEntry * _new_entry;
    int newptr;
    if (_obj == NULL || strlen(_obj_name) == 0) return TCL_ERROR;
    char * _name = (char *) malloc (strlen(_obj_name));
    if (_name == NULL) return TCL_ERROR;
    _new_entry=Tcl_CreateHashEntry(hash_table,_name,&newptr);
    if (newptr == 0) {
        printf("Error: obj with name %s already exists\n",_obj_name);
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    Tcl_SetHashValue(_new_entry,_obj);
    return TCL_OK;
}

void removeMyObj(const char * _obj_name) {
    Tcl_HashEntry * _entry;
    _entry = Tcl_FindHashEntry(hash_table,_obj_name);
    // entry was found
    if (_entry != NULL) {
        My_Obj * _my_obj = (My_Obj * ) Tcl_GetHashValue(_entry);
        Tcl_DeleteHashEntry(_entry);
        delete _my_obj;
    }
    return;
}

My_Obj * getMyObj(const char * _obj_name) {
    Tcl_HashEntry * _entry;
    _entry = Tcl_FindHashEntry(hash_table,_obj_name);
    // entry was found
    if (_entry != NULL) {
        My_Obj * _my_obj = (My_Obj * ) Tcl_GetHashValue(_entry);
        return _my_obj;
    }
    return NULL;
}

// The problem is that in this function I should remove the object from hash table and delete it afterwards.


extern "C" void My_Obj_destroy(ClientData clientData) {

    if (clientData != NULL) {
        My_Obj * _my_obj = (My_Obj *) clientData;
        removeMyObj(_my_obj); // should be removed from the hash table but it is receiving pointer to my_obj and not it's name
        delete _my_obj ;
        _my_obj = NULL;
    }
    return;
}
```

thank you

Comment: Just add the name into your obj

Comment: I don't want to do this because then I need to implement a wrapper to my object. I also can create a table that links my object pointers to a name that I give it but again I thought there is something better

Comment: Create a struct with the name and the object, and put this into the hashtable

Comment: and how I will find my object when this hash table contains this struct?? key will be string/pointer?

Comment: Are you sure to understand pointer and struct ? If `s` is the struct with `name`and `obj`, do the look up with the name and get your obj with `s->obj`, on destroy use `s->name` to call remove.

Comment: Why not just use `Tcl_DeleteHashEntry` that remove object using pointer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this:

1. Keep a copy of the name of the object in the object.
2. Keep a pointer to the `Tcl_HashEntry` created when you make a name for the object in the hash table. (It's just a pointer, but it is guaranteed to be valid from creation until it is deleted.)

In your case, it's probably best to keep that `Tcl_HashEntry *` — it's the value returned by `Tcl_CreateHashEntry()` or looked up with `Tcl_FindHashEntry()` — so that you can delete easily. The only tricky bit is that this means you *must* make sure that you are careful about deletion order, which means taking care when you seek to delete the overall hash table.

Comment: Implementation note: `Tcl_CreateHashEntry()` and `Tcl_FindHashEntry()` are really macro front-ends for the same API function — they do almost the same thing after all — but treat them as separate.

Comment: Also, there is a separate call for getting from a `Tcl_HashEntry` back to its key. It's a cheap call, but type-messy (because of the polymorphic nature of the C API).